# javascript timeout/sleep using setTimeout()

Tags: javascript, jquery, timeout, sleep, timing

How can I set a 2 second timeout to wait for page controls to be populated? I want to use javascript I have tried the following but to no avail:

```
setTimeout(function(){},2000);

setTimeout(2000);
```

Anyone able to provide a pointer?

Comment: whatever you want to do after the timeout has to be inside the callback function passed to `setTimeout()` as in the first example you have given

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
setTimeout(function(){
  //put your code in here to be delayed by 2 seconds
},2000);
```

The code you want to delay needs to sit inside the setTimeout function.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
$('input').click(function () {
    var that = $(this);
    setTimeout(function() { alertMsg(that); },2000);
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Cerebrl/4MVvN/)

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: Part of this answer is identical to [another more popular answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39914235/4376643), but this answer also includes output to make clear that the constructed `sleep()` permits independent loops in the same thread to run interleaved.

ECMAScript Latest Draft (ECMA-262). As of 2019, supported in most broswers, but not IE.

```
function sleep(n) { return new Promise(resolve=>setTimeout(resolve,n)); }

async function LoopA() {
    for (let i=0;i<10;i++) {
        console.log("LoopA i=",i,
                    ",sec=",performance.now().toFixed(0)/1000);
        await sleep(1000);
    }
}
async function LoopB() {
    for (let i=0;i<10;i++) {
        console.log("LoopB i=",i,
                    ",sec=",performance.now().toFixed(0)/1000);
        await sleep(1000);
    }
}
LoopA();
LoopB();
```

has sample output:

```
LoopA i= 0 ,sec= 1648.665 
LoopB i= 0 ,sec= 1648.665 
LoopA i= 1 ,sec= 1649.666
LoopB i= 1 ,sec= 1649.667
LoopA i= 2 ,sec= 1650.667
LoopB i= 2 ,sec= 1650.669
LoopA i= 3 ,sec= 1651.669
LoopB i= 3 ,sec= 1651.67
LoopA i= 4 ,sec= 1652.67
LoopB i= 4 ,sec= 1652.671
LoopA i= 5 ,sec= 1653.671 
LoopB i= 5 ,sec= 1653.672 
LoopA i= 6 ,sec= 1654.672 
LoopB i= 6 ,sec= 1654.674 
LoopA i= 7 ,sec= 1655.674 
LoopB i= 7 ,sec= 1655.675 
LoopA i= 8 ,sec= 1656.675 
LoopB i= 8 ,sec= 1656.676 
LoopA i= 9 ,sec= 1657.677 
LoopB i= 9 ,sec= 1657.678
```