# Stop making form to reload a page

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I need help!

I need that, after the user submits the form below, the email is validated, an alert is displayed and changes a part of the screen with the message "Welcome + email" for at least 5sec.

```
<form name="formcontact1" action="#">
    <input type='text' name='email' size="36" placeholder="Your e-mail :)"/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT" onclick="ValidateEmail(document.formcontact1.email)" />
</form>
```

I have the following script to validate email that is working perfect!

```
function ValidateEmail(inputText) {

  var mailformat = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
  if (inputText.value.match(mailformat)) {
    alert("Email " + inputText.value + " has been sent");
    document.getElementById('title1').innerHTML = 'Welcome ' + inputText.value;
    return true;

  }
  else {
    alert("Invalid Email");
    document.formcontact1.email.focus();
    return false;
  }

}
```

After the button is clicked it shows the alert message "EMAIL xxx HAS BEEN SENT" (correct).

I need that it update part of the page with a message "WELCOME xxxxx".

The problem is after the alert message be shown. It update part of the page but reload. Is there a way to avoid this and keep 5 seconds before reload?.  THANKS !!!

Comment: Have you looked into query strings?

Comment: Maybe you could try to implement a timer ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/18254210/9069343

Comment: Why not submit through ajax and avoid the page reload all togather?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to use preventDefault() which stops the default behaviour of refreshing the page on form submit function 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

And then use setTimeout()-function to wait x amount of seconds.

```
<form name="formcontact1" action="#">
    <input type='text' name='email' size="36" placeholder="Your e-mail :)"/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT" onclick="ValidateEmail(event, document.formcontact1.email)" />
</form>

ValidateEmail(event, inputText) {
event.preventDefault();


  var mailformat = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
  if (inputText.value.match(mailformat)) {
    alert("Email " + inputText.value + " has been sent");
    document.getElementById('title1').innerHTML = 'Welcome ' + inputText.value;
    return true;

  }
  else {
    alert("Invalid Email");
    document.formcontact1.email.focus();
    return false;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the browser to call `submit` event's built-in handler (which reloads the page), you'll need to return `false` in successful check branch as well. Then add `setTimeout` call there right before returning `false` that will reload the page using `window.location.reload()` after a delay.

UPD: The handler part would look like this:

```js
if (inputText.value.match(mailformat)) {
    alert("Email " + inputText.value + " has been sent");
    document.getElementById('title1').innerHTML = 'Welcome ' + inputText.value;
    setTimeout(function() {location.reload();}, 5000);
}
else {
 // same as before
}
return false; // for both branches
```